# How to find 9s complement of a given decimal number?

Tags: twos-complement

Given decimal number=12
One way to find 9s complement is to simply find 10s complement and subtract 1. By this method I get answer=87.

However can i solve this problem by first finding the equivalent of 12 in base 9 number system which would be 13. Now if I find 9s complement of this number using the formula r^n -N answer would be 81-12.
Please suggest what's wrong ?

Comment: This sounds like a homework problem. Can you show us your work?

Comment: No this is not a homework problem.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Method_of_complements I think you are confusing 2 formulas. The thing you are looking at should add to 8, not 9, I think (still subtracting 1). Your goal would be to do 10^2-12-1 to get the 9s complement